# Bug in Golang xml/encoding RawToken()?

Tags: xml, go, marshalling, xml-namespaces

I have a Go code:

```
xmlData := `<foo xmlns:="url"/>`
xmlDec := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader([]byte(xmlData)))
rawToken, _ := xmlDec.RawToken()
fmt.Println(rawToken)
```

Now interesting part, let's use Go 1.14.0

Output: `{{ foo} [{{xmlns } url}]}`

Switch to Go 1.18.0

Output: `{{ foo} [{{ xmlns:} url}]}`

In the first output `xml.Name.Space` = `"xmlns"` and `xml.Name.Local` = `""`

In the second output `xml.Name.Space` = `""` and `xml.Name.Local` = `"xmlns:"`

Can anybody explain me what is going on?

Comment: `<foo xmlns:="url"/>` is not a correct namespace. Either don't use a `:` (`<foo xmlns="url"/>`)  or define prefix for a namespace (`<foo xmlns:abc="url"/>`)

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed indeed, the idea was to have the same output as Go 1.14. Then the `xml.Name.Local` = `"xmlns:"` is also invalid! But as you see it is parsed in Go 1.18. Not sure that the case only in xml invalidity

Comment: I would suggest that both versions should have raised an error at line 2

Comment: There were a bunch of xml bug fixes over the course of those releases, have you checked if any apply to namespace handling?

Comment: @JimB even if they were, why invalid xml still being parsed, that's what I'm concerned about. Go 1.14 could parse "xmlns:" as `namespace=xmlns"` and `tag=""`, why would then Go 1.18 parse that as `namespace=""` and `tag="xmlns:"`. If you say "bug fixes" then it should be already fixed and report an error, but it doesnt ;)

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed it should raise, if we talk about correctness of XML, but in fact, Go 1.18 doesnt raise that. And even more, Go 1.14 still parses that in more correct way than Go 1.18 (even if both are false)

Comment: I don't know, just trying to point you to some clues about where the behavior might have changed. I recall something about namespaces, but it's been a couple years.

Comment: @JimB seems that I found that commit, so try to figure out how to fix it on my end, but not sure :/, thanks anyway for the support